# Insertion Sort comparison count

Tags: java, sorting, count

I've seen topics like this before but with little to no help.
I have a method like this:

```
comparecount=0;
for(int i = 1; i < tab.length; i++) {
        comparecount++;

        for(int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            //comparecount++;
            if(tab[j]<tab[j-1]) {
                comparecount++;
                swap(tab,j,j-1);
                adjustcount+=3;
            }
        }

    }
```

For the input 8 5 6 1 7 2, this is supposed to produce 13 comparisons, but mine does 15. In the interest of full disclosure this is part of my homework, the algorithm prints the trace just fine as requested, so I'm struggling to find where im getting those extra 2 comparisons

Comment: Insertion sort has a complexity of ``O(n^2)`` ,   So for 6 elements, you should get around ``36/2`` which is 18 comparison. Why do you think you should get 13 comparison ?

Comment: Thats the number of comparisons given by the professor. As you can see theres also an adjust count which works just fine, so im guessing the algorithm is correct

Comment: Check the exact input, if the order is the same as your professor gave you. Because in this case even though the elements are the same, if their order is different, you will get different results

Comment: It is the same 100%, there is also a trace algorith part i redacted here which fits the answer completely

Comment: In this case, your professor gave you a wrong result. You can sort the array by hand, and also will get 15 swaps ...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how I solved this.

The above algorithm compares everything, so incase `1 5 6 8 | 7 2  -->
1 5 6 7 8 | 2` it counted comparisons like 7 compared to 8, 7 compared to 6, it inserted it, and went on to 6 compared to 5 etc. How i reached 13 was stopping the count once it inserted the 7.